# Missing fonts in Xvfb

Tags: fonts, xvfb

I've installed Ubuntu 12.04.3 64-bit as a guest under VMplayer running on my Win7 host.

After Ubuntu installs, I launch and open a terminal.

I then enter the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine
sudo apt-get install xvfb
sudo apt-get install xfonts-100dpi xfonts-75dpi xfonts-scalable xfonts-cyrillic
```

When I launch xvfb, I get the following error:

```
“[dix] Could not init font path element /var/lib/defoma/x-ttcidfont-conf.d/dirs/TrueType, removing from list!”
```

"x-ttcidfont-conf" *should have* been installed with "wine" as I got the same EULA when I install manually.  However, it never gets recognized and when I check font folders, they're empty.

I've tried these steps as well:

1. Alternate attempt 1:

   - `sudo apt-get -y install x-ttcidfont-conf cabextract ttf-mscorefonts-installer`
   - `sudo dpkg-reconfigure x-ttcidfont-conf`
2. Alternate attempt 2:

   - Reset Ubuntu
   - At login screen: Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd>
   - Login
   - kill x server: `sudo service lightdm stop`
   - generate new xorg.conf file: `sudo X -configure`

     - This will create a 'xorg.conf.new' file in your current dir
   - return to GUI: `sudo start lightdm`
   - Login through UI
   - Open & edit xorg.conf.new and add the following two lines:

   > > FontPath "/var/lib/defoma/x-ttcidfont-conf.d/dirs/CID"
   > >
   > > FontPath "/var/lib/defoma/x-ttcidfont-conf.d/dirs/TrueType"
3. Save & exit
4. Logout of UI
5. At login screen: Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd>
6. Login
7. kill x server: `sudo service lightdm stop`
8. rename and move: `sudo mv xorg.conf.new /etc/X11/xorg.conf`
9. return to GUI: `sudo start lightdm`

I fully admit I'm a linux/ubuntu/xvfb noob...but I am good at Google searches and nothing seems to work.

What am I missing?

---

I've tried:

```
sudo apt-get -y install x-ttcidfont-conf
[sudo] password for <user>:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
x-ttcidfont-conf is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 17 not - upgraded.
```

and still get the same error message.

---

I've also tried:

1. sudo apt-get upgrade
2. Restarted ubuntu
3. retried

Get same results.   :-(

---

There is an in-house shell script that launches Xvfb followed by an application and apparently just hangs as a result.  The first line in the shell script is:

Xvfb :2 &

And simply executing that command outside of the shell script causes the same error.

I've read in one of the many pages to help resolve this that I need an xorg.conf in a folder to point to font folders.  I tried to create this and for the other fonts such as xfont-100dpi, xfont-75dpi, etc. there is content in the folders.  Why am I not able to get any content in the equivalent font folder for x-ttcidfont-conf TrueType font?

Comment: Can you upgrade those packages with `sudo apt-get upgrade` then restart your session?

Comment: Could you explain what is the adverse effect of that warning? What are you trying to accomplish installing that font?

Comment: @gdaemon did you manage to solve it ?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the package [`x-ttcidfont-conf`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/x-ttcidfont-conf). A simple `sudo apt-get -y install x-ttcidfont-conf` should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found that by executing the following command, I was able to resolve the problem:

```
mkfontdir
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I've found this does not permanently solve my problem. Seems a reboot brought back problem and discovered through another web-site that x-ttcidfonts-conf has been deprecated on Ubuntu.

http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.multimedia.puredata.general/88691